# Twitter Bootstrap - mobile version only?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a website for a client that needs to have a mobile version. They already have a site right now that they want to keep, but simply want a totally different mobile version - so, i was wondering if the Twitter Bootstrap can be chopped down, so that it only uses the mobile aspect of the framework?

Apologies if my question doesn't make sense, if it doesn't, feel free to ask any more questions and i'll try to better explain myself.

To summarize, i simply want to design a mobile version of a site using Twitter Bootstrap, but ONLY a mobile version - no desktop version is needed because one already exists on the clients domain.

Comment: You can edit the .Less files. But, if you are doing mobile only, consider jQuery Mobile. That would be a better choice. http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: Excellent, that looks like a better all 'round solution. Thanks!

Comment: @NikkiMather I am also trying to create a mobile only version of a website. Which one did you end up choosing - Twitter Bootstrap or jQuery Mobile?

Comment: Late reply, but... jQuery Mobile :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Robin2k mentioned, the 'bootstrap-responsive.css' / 'bootstrap-responsive.min.css' file will make your website work well on most mobile devices.

If you want to chop down the script just to decrease load times, the best advice I can give you is:

1. Make sure to use the `.min.css` and `.min.js` files, they're considerably smaller
2. Try [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com), they will cache and compress your bootstrap files to make your site load considerably faster

Comment: And CloudFlare will make your site unavailable regularly.

Comment: @jgillich I've found that CloudFlare's reliability has drastically improved over the past few months. Amazon also has a similar service, though it is much more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

you can use twitters that property which only show elements on mobile size. 
then the size of the page will increase, it will hide all page. and nobody able to see it on desktop version .
http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely only use mobile parts of Twitter Bootstrap as a starting point.

**The more important question is:** what is the purpose of the separate mobile site? Why would a user want different content on their phone vs. a laptop or desktop? The most future-friendly way to go would be to make the current site responsive/adaptive so the same content is there, but adapted for smaller screens.

Just my 2c, but you can definitely cut out the parts of Bootstrap you don't like.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I'm really not sure why they want a separate version as opposed to an integrated version incorporating their current design; i just know they don't want to change or use their current desktop version as a basis for the mobile version - they just want 2 separate entities. Thanks for your input.

Comment: No problem, I understand how it is to be at the mercy of a client. It might be good to ask about the users, though.

Also, check out [this post on media queries.](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

Answer (score 0):

For the client to want a mobile site that offers a different experience is perfectly understandable. Accessing a website via a mobile vs a desktop presents two use cases, and depending on those use cases, there may be site features a user will care or not care about depending on the device he/she uses to access it. Therefore a one size fits all is not always the best choice.